# Recaptcha "incorrect-captcha-sol"

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

Actual keys redacted" **I'm implementing a simple login form with ReCaptcha.**
The ReCaptcha gives me this error:
**"The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again. (reCAPTCHA said: incorrect-captcha-sol)"**
This is my code:

**Index.php**

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="verify.php">
            <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="78">Username</td>
                        <td width="6">:</td>
                        <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>

<html>
    <title>Title Dolan Webiste</title>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=actual_key_redacted"></script>
        <noscript>
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=actual_key_redacted" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br />
            <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"> </textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
        </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Verify.php**

```
<?php
    echo "<pre> _POST: =========\n";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "\n=========\n</pre>";

    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "private_key_here";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.".
            "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
    } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    }
?>
```

I have no clue what I did wrong. Any help?

P.s. Yes, I do have the recaptchalib.php in the same directory.

Comment: You show that you entered your public key in the HTML but you are not indicating that you entered your private key in the PHP.  Did you?

Comment: I did, I changed it in an attempt to hide my private key (It could be abused or something)

Comment: I am 100% sure I entered the correct code, I copy-pasted it.

Comment: Don't copy/paste code if you have no clue what it does, or how to debug it when it goes wrong.

Comment: What @PeteR said.  You cannot blindly copy/paste code if you lack the fundamentals, like how the re-Captcha widget needs to be _inside_ of the `form` container.

Answer (score 0):

See this...

```
$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]
```

The `$_POST` variable array comes from the `form` data upon submit.  The problem is, how can the form data post array contain `recaptcha_challenge_field` and `recaptcha_response_field` when you've failed to put these fields in the `form` container?

You **must** put the reCaptcha widget *inside* of your `form` container, or *between* your `<form>` and `</form>` tags.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="verify.php">

    .... the rest of your form here

    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=actual_key_redacted">
    </script>
    <noscript>
     <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=actual_key_redacted"
         height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
     <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
     </textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
         value="manual_challenge">
    </noscript>

</form>
```

However, not sure why you didn't notice the missing post data when you did your `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Is this still valid or shall I use the examples posted by [google recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start) ?

Comment: @IronFist, AFAIK, there is nothing wrong with this answer and it applies to the same version as you've linked.  If you have information to the contrary, please share.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize that your answer is for Disabled JS users. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @IronFist, its for both, hence the `script` tag above the `noscript` tag.